# Fetch all of wordpress (less header/footer) into magento. I can only get the posts

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

http://inchoo.net/wordpress/how-to-use-wordpress-home-page-in-magento-home-page-cms-page/comment-page-1/#comment-8020

to accomplish getting my wordpress to show some info inside magento (blog posts) but I can not understand how to pull in the entire page.  The only part I don't want is the header and footer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iclude the `wp-blog-header.php` to your magento template.
If you add the following line at the top of your magento template, you will have access to all WP commands:

`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php');`

(make sure you use the right path)

Now you just ned to [create a loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action) and display the post. You may also get posts from a [specific category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) if you wish.